# Use of read -d option on Ubuntu Bash Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

im trying to use that option of read command in my script but i get only the error message 'read: -d ilegal option' when i execute it. This is the code

```
 #!bin/bash

 read -d "." -p "Write here: " var
 var>$1
```

Im trying to type the same code on terminal and its ok there. 
I've checked the version's shell and is bash. Thanks for help

Comment: Probably you are running it with `sh readit.sh` instead of using `bash` and fix `bin/bash` to `/bin/bash`

Comment: Your shebang path should be `/bin/bash` not `bin/bash`.

Comment: Your shebang is faulty, try using `#!/bin/bash` instead

Comment: What do you run `var>$1` for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your script explicitly with `bash script.sh` not `sh script.sh`. Also make sure you have bash: `bash --version`.